# Obtaining access tokens by Sign in with Twitter for GET search/tweets

Tags: java, android, twitter

I am new to development with Android and Twitter. As mentioned in the documentation, an individual is allowed to search 180 keywords in a 15-minute window, and a particular application is allowed to search 450 keywords within 15 minutes.

After obtaining access tokens, we were able to search for 450 keywords within 15 minutes, but we weren't able to search for 180 keywords within 15 minutes. How would I obtain this using the Sign-In with Twitter?

These are the references I've used so far:

- https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/obtaining-access-tokens
- https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter

How would I achieve the same functionality?